# Excel: Frequency of articles ordered together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, analysis

I am looking for help, with an analysis I would like to perform in Excel.

Available data:
Sales history including the Order number & Article number.

Example of the available data:

***Order number and article number***

{[image: Order number and article number]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjkqe.png)

I am looking for a way in Excel to determine the following data:

***Frequency ordered together***

[image: Frequency ordered together]

The goal:
Create an visualization of frequency ordered together.

[image]

Hope it is clear what I aim to do.
Looking forward to your replies.
This is the file I have prepared: [File.xlsx](https://we.tl/t-38sj76BpDj)

Comment: I think you need to use VBA (possibly powerQuery) to transform your data from your input to output. I don't see how formulas could do it.

Answer (score 0):

gns100 is correct. You can do this with Power Query (now called "Get & Transform"). Here's how:

First, format your data as a Table. Put your cursor anywhere in the data and press Ctrl+T.

I've renamed my Table "orders". The Table Name box is in the Properties group to the far left of the Table Design tab.

There's a great feature of Get & Transform called "Merge queries". But to use it, you need a Query. So, put your cursor anywhere in your Table and click "From Table/Range" in the "Get & Transform Data" group on the Data tab of the ribbon.

[image: Get & Transform Data From Table/Range]

The Power Query window will open. Click the "Append Queries" drop-down in the Combine group on the ribbon and select "Append Queries as New".

[image: Append Queries as New]

Select "orders" in both drop-downs, change the join kind to "Inner (only matching rows)" and click the "Order" column in each of the displayed tables.

[image: Append Queries as New - dialog]

So, we're telling Power Query to join orders to itself using matches from the Order column. After you click OK, it will look like this:

[image: Merged query - initial appearance]

Click the double-arrow button in the top-right corner of the third column to expand the joined table. Since the order column from both sides of the join will be identical, you can deselect it, like this:

[image: Expand columns dialog]

After you've expanded the rows, you'll see there are 16 rows for each Order. These are the combinations of each of the articles in the order with each of the other articles. There are four articles in each order, so combining each with each of the others produces four rows per article. If you filter the left-most column on Order=10, you'll see this:

[image: Order 10]

Clear the filter from Order. There's one last thing to do. We aren't interested in the rows where the article is in the same order as itself.

So, we'll add a column that shows TRUE if article equals orders.article.

Click "Add Column">"Custom Column" on the Ribbon. You can configure it like this:
[image: ArticleMatches definition]

When you click OK, it will add the new column (ArticleMatches) to the Query. Now, you can just filter that column on FALSE. Since that column is not that interesting, you can right click on ArticleMatches and choose RemoveColumn. This happens after the filter, so it still works!

That's pretty much it. You just click "Close & Load" on the Home tab and now you have your data showing which article was present with which other article in an order.

[image: End result]

If you want to go a bit further and calculate the frequencies as well, you can go back to your Query (right click it and choose "Edit"), then click "Group By" in the Power Query window and configure the dialog like this:

[image: Group By in Power Query]

Again, click "Close & Load" on the Home tab and you'll get your results!

[image: Frequencies]